# How to concatenate items in a list?

Tags: python

I want to concatenate items in a list if the last character of the list is not a "."

```
l=["First item","Second item","Third item.","Fourth item."]

abc=[element for element in l if not element[-1]=="."]
```

I tried to use a list comprehension but I don't know how to concatenate two items using list comprehension.

What I want:

```
abc=["First itemSecond itemThird item.","Fourth item."]
```

Comment: I believe you can't do in a clean way using list comprehensions, so it would be better to try using a for loop.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli i tried a for loop but it concatened item 1 with 2, item 2 with item 3 and not item 1 with item 2 and 3

Comment: Well, so there is something wrong or missing within your for loop. Try to modify it and see what you can come up with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop over your list items, building strings. Whenever the current item ends in a period, append the currently built string to the final result, and start building a new string:

```
l=["First item","Second item","Third item.","Fourth item."]

result = []
curr_str = ""
for item in l:
    curr_str += item
    if item[-1] == ".":
        result.append(curr_str)
        curr_str = ""

 ['First itemSecond itemThird item.', 'Fourth item.']
```

Comment: Unless you're code-golfing, the string method `endswith` might be preferable to `[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

now this is a messy answer but i'd expect it to work:

```
w = ''.join(l).split('.')
x = [item + '.' for item in w]
```

Comment: I have this error ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'```

Comment: @ayansalt2 solved by editing the code in this answer.

Comment: This doesn't return the desired result as you add a '.' as the last element

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

l=["First item","Second item","Third item.","Fourth item."]
abc=[element for element in l if not element[-1]=="."]

Add one more line
abc = [" ".join(x for x in abc)]
abc will still be a list having result

Answer (score 0):

you can join and split:

```
l=["First item","Second item","Third item.","Fourth item."]
new_l = [element.lstrip()+'.' for element in ' '.join(l).split('.')][:-1]
```

Output `new_l`:

```
['First item Second item Third item.', 'Fourth item.']
```